# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload was not handled by any navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

here is my App.js :

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import React from "react";
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./LoginScreen";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={
          AsyncStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn?") === "true"
            ? "LoginScreen"
            : "HomeScreen"
        }
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen component={LoginScreen} name="LoginScreen" />

        <Stack.Screen component={HomeScreen} name="HomeScreen" />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

here is my HomeScreen.js :

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import Message from "./Message";

export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const refForScrollView = useRef();
  const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState("");
  const [tempNameValue, setTempNameValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    refForScrollView.current.scrollToEnd();
    AsyncStorage.getItem("name")
      .then((name) => setTempNameValue(name))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    navigation.navigate("Login");
  }, []);
  const data = [
    { message: tempNameValue },
    { message: "heavy rider" },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
    {
      message: "My Name Is Dev",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={require("./assets/official-whatsapp-background-image1.jpg")}
        style={styles.poti}
      />
      <View style={styles.messages}>
        <ScrollView ref={refForScrollView}>
          {data.map((user) => {
            return <Message message={user.message} />;
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bottom}>
        <TextInput placeholder="Enter Your Message" style={styles.input} />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sendButton}>
          <Icon name="md-send" style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 18 }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <StatusBar hidden />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignContent: "center",
  },
  input: {
    display: "flex",
    width: "80%",
    borderRadius: 200,
    paddingLeft: 12,
    height: 45,
    backgroundColor: "#f1f1fa",
  },
  bottom: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    flexDirection: "row",
    bottom: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    padding: 10,
  },
  poti: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
  sendButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#3894A3",
    borderRadius: 100,
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingLeft: 17,
    position: "relative",
  },
  messages: {
    height: "89%",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    width: "100%",
  },
});
```

and here is my LoginScreen.js :

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import Dialog from "react-native-dialog";
export default function App({ navigation }) {
  const [tempValue, setTempValue] = useState("");
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e);
  };
  const Submit = () => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn?", "true");
    AsyncStorage.setItem("name", inputValue);
    navigation.navigate("Home");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn?")
      .then((value) => console.log(value))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Dialog.Container visible={true}>
        <Dialog.Input
          placeholder="Enter Your Name : "
          value={inputValue}
          onChangeText={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        />
        <Dialog.Button label="Submit" onPress={Submit} />
        <StatusBar style="auto" hidden />
      </Dialog.Container>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
});
```

and here is my Message.js :

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
export default function Message({ message }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.message}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, color: "white" }}>{message}</Text>
      <StatusBar hidden />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  message: {
    backgroundColor: "#3894A3",
    padding: 11,
    borderRadius: 15,
    marginBottom: 10,
    textAlign: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    margin: 15,
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    color: "white",
  },
});
```

first i tried to do it in if else so if logged in is true then go to home screen else go to login screen then came to initial route but both are having same errors what am i doing wrong here
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to navigate to 'Login' and 'Home' but you gave screens name 'LoginScreen' and 'HomeScreen' so use these instead

```
navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')
navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
```

Comment: Thank you man kind and legendary of you to answer.